# ¿Creación de un enlace simbólico a un archivo con la clase Os.symlink ()?

Tags: android

Buenas a todos, he hecho esta pregunta para poder ayudarme a resolver mi problema. Quiero ser capas para crear un enlace simbólico a un archivo que está en la memoria interna con la memoria externa, he utilizado la clase o el método Os.symlink (), pero esto me dio el resultado del error típico: "la aplicación Es detenido ".

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
File path=new File("/sdcard/Music.mp3");

    String symLink=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        Os.symlink(path.getAbsolutePath(), symLink);
    } catch (ErrnoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

He añadido los permisos de lectura y escritura a la memoria externa, si saben cómo solucionar mi error u otra forma de lograr mi objetivo, por favor, me comentan.

Comment: Algun mensaje en el LogCat? Que sistema operativo ya que como sabes para os 5.0 o mayor se requieren ciertos permisos en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Gracias amigo me solucionaste el error yo estaba ejecutando el app en un dispositivo versión 4.1.2, pero no sabrás un método que se compatible con la versión 4.0 en adelante.

Comment: @Abraham.P si se llego a solucionar el problema podrías agregar la solución y marcar como solucionado. gracias

Comment: No hay problema lo realizare.